# Русский текст в MySQL отображается как китайские иероглифы

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Есть два сервера с аналогичной структурой баз данных. Файлы *my.ini* также полностью аналогичны. Глобальные настройки баз данных, связанные с кодировкой, тоже одинаковы и выглядят так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сессионные настройки тоже одинаковы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом русский текст в одной базе данных отображается нормально, а в другой русский текст после вставки:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
insert  into `apps`(...) values (...);
```

отображается как китайские иероглифы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Схема таблицы выглядит следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE `apps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `program_change` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=67 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

В чём проблема, и как правильно вставить русский текст в эту таблицу?

**P.S.** Как я выяснила после, `SET NAMES` не имеет никакого влияния на поля типа `BLOB`.

Comment: У вас на рисунках в одной базе данных character_set_results в кодировке cp1251, в другой - utf8.